# How Grub top title can be changed

Tags: grub2, kernel

I am just wondering that 'How I can change the title on very top for Grub' - where it's written like 'GNU Grub version 1.99-21ubuntu3.4'? I am not asking for the menu entry, or to change labels of menus.

I just wish to write something as I want, at the very top in Grub menu.

Anyone, please help me.

Thanking you.

Raihan

Comment: Hi Friends, I haven't got any response. No one knows about this - I don't believe. Please come back to me....Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you cannot do that through configuration.

More precisely, this is a localized string "GNU GRUB  version %s", which resides in `/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod`.

A few solutions, if you really want to change it:

- Build your own packages, with a patch in the source code (see `const char *msg` in `grub-core/normal/main.c`) or in the `po/` locales;
- Modify the appropriate `po` file with, for example, poedit, then recompile it to an `mo` file and put it in /boot/grub/locale.